# Set Window Size using API SendMessage

Tags: excel, vba, windows, api

I found code to open a PDF document using VBA for Excel. The procedure *OpenPDF* is called with `OpenPDF "FullFileName", 3, 143` where '3' is the page number to be displayed. "143" is received by *OpenPDF* as argument *strZoomValue As String* and then passed to an API.

```
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const VK_RETURN = &HD
Public Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100

SendMessage lSecondChildFirstWindow, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, ByVal strZoomValue
PostMessage lSecondChildFirstWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0
```

I believe "143" causes the window to be maximized which don't want. The window should be tiled. I wonder if I could just change the 'ZoomValue' to achieve that but to construct the *lParam* argument appears to be a rather complex science, different for each value of *wParam*. So, I wonder if someone might just tell me what I need. While at it, what's the "ByVal" doing in the API call? Could that be replaced with "(strZoomValue)"? And why that? *lParam* is of `Any` data type. Why can't the number be assigns as a Variant or even as Long or, at least, as String without further precautions?

BTW, I removed the two above lines from the code and got a maximized window. Therefore I presume that Windows remembers the size last used for Acrobat Reader, which was maximized by the "143" call. Therefore just ignoring the problem isn't a plausible option.

Comment: I think this goes a little way to answering your other question but IDK about dual monitors as they can be set up as clone, extended display and other bells and whistles which might need to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to [this article](https://myengineeringworld.net/2013/04/open-pdf-file-with-vba.html) ?

I think you need to extend it and use [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos). There's a good example [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-code-to-move-windows-via-call-to-api.961208/).

E.g. basic example with Notepad.exe:

```
Option Explicit

' https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-code-to-move-windows-via-call-to-api.961208/
Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal x As Long, _
    ByVal y As Long, _
    ByVal cx As Long, _
    ByVal cy As Long, _
    ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    
' moves to top of Zorder
Public Const HWND_TOP = 0
' Overwrites cx & cy to not resize window. // Variatus - I think you don't want to do this...
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1

    
' launch a notepad exe
Sub LaunchNotepad()
    Call Shell("NOTEPAD.EXE", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub

' return the hwnd for a notepad
' dunno if multiple notepads running
Function FindNotepadHwnd() As LongPtr
    FindNotepadHwnd = FindWindow("Notepad", vbNullString)
End Function

' test
Sub Test()
    Dim hwnd As LongPtr
    
    Call LaunchNotepad
    hwnd = FindNotepadHwnd()
    ' 30 and 30 puts window near top left
    ' 280 and 540 makes it twice as long as wide
    hwnd = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 30, 30, 280, 560, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. You guessed my source correctly :-) And thanks for the encouragement. I shall use `SetWindowPos`.